Sci-fi movie from maybe 70's/80's with big creatures guarding a wall
It was a movie where a group of people travalled in a spaceship to an unknown planet. They met sorts of creatures like flying dinosaurs. The creatures spent the whole day guarding a big wall.
I was very young so it's kinda hard to remember. I didn't want to say "pterodactyls", I wasn't sure if this will confuse you more than anything else. The scene I remember is a group of persons trying to get back to their spaceship or maybe a time machine like this one. They had to climb a wall where those creatures were resting to get to that machine. From time to time, one of these creatures wakes up (with a big zoom into her white eyes) and would fly screaming and taking with her a victim from the group.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Just a wild guess, but "Flying dinosaur" could mean a pterodactyl.  That means it could be "Voyage to the Prehistoric Planet" or "Voyage to the Prehistoric Planet Women", which both "borrowed" footage from the Soviet 1962 "Planeta Bur".

"Forbidden Planet" is also a possibility.

We're just chucking guesses around now, folks. It's best to wait for the question to improve.

Hi guys and thanks for the responses.
I was very young so it's kinda hard to remember.
I didnt want to say "pterodactyls", I wasnt sure if this will confuse you more than anything else.
The scene I remember is a group of persons trying to get back to their spaceship or maybe a timemachine like this one : http://img.rp.vhd.me/2872481_l1.jpg
They had to climb a wall where those creatures were resting to get to that machine.
From time to time, one of these creatures wakes up (a big zoom were made into her white eyes)  and could fly screaming and taking with her a victim from the group.

Not an unknown planet, but the flying dinosaurs on a wall, and camera zooms into their eyes bring to mind At the Earth's Core, (1976), with Peter Cushing and Caroline Munro.

Dr. Abner Perry, a British Victorian period scientist (Cushing), and
  his US financier David Innes (McClure) make a test run of their Iron
  Mole drilling machine in a Welsh mountain, but end up in a strange
  underground labyrinth ruled by a species of giant telepathic flying
  reptiles, the Mahars, and full of prehistoric monsters and cavemen.
  They are captured by the Mahars, who keep primitive humans as their
  slaves through mind control.

I remember the there would be a closeup of a Mahar's eye to indicate it was using mind control to command a slave, or to spellbind a human before flying down and carrying him or her off.
The full movie is on Youtube.  The scene with flying dinosaurs is here.

That's the movie !
Thank you very much.
